# splitting and rejoining PDFs with Poppler results in larger file? (despite stripping metadata)

Tags: pdf, metadata, exiftool, poppler, qpdf

If I have a multi page PDF, and split it into separate pages using the excellent [poppler package](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) (installed on macOS using `brew install poppler`) like this:

`pdfseparate foo.pdf bar-%04d.pdf`

and then rejoin the resulting bar-####.pdf files, like so:

`pdfunite bar-*.pdf baz.pdf`

The resulting baz.pdf appears to have the same content, but **the file is much larger**.

At first I assumed because there would be duplicate metadata in the result or something. But even if I strip all metadata from all files, i.e. from the input, as well as the intermediate bar-####.pdf files, as well as the resulting output file, using [exiftool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/index.html) and [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
# command line steps to strip metadata from (and re-linearize) example.pdf :
exiftool -all= -overwrite_original example.pdf ;
mv example.pdf temp.pdf ;
qpdf --linearize temp.pdf example.pdf
```

Then *still* the resulting baz.pdf file is much larger than the original input.

What can be the cause of this? What else can there be in a multiple-page PDF file other than it's bare contents? Assuming that poppler's `pdfseparate` and `pdfunite` leave the actual content itself untouched, and that my stripping of metadata is correct.

Or is it possible that `pdfseparate` and `pdfunite` somehow decompose and reconstruct the PDF contents in a way that is lossless but sub-optimal? (I don't know enough about the inner structure of PDF files but I can imagine there are a lot of different ways to encode the same content)

By the way if I inspect any of the involved PDF files using `exiftool somefile.pdf` it does indeed show no metadata at all (and Linearized: Yes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PDF pages use shared resources such as fonts, images, etc. When you split the document the shared resources go into each resulted file. When you merge those files the resources might not by merged back (this depends on how the merger tool is implemented) thus resulting a much larger file.

Comment: Thanks, yes, of course, that makes sense. Would you happen to know of any way to prevent this? Typically, I do the above process to replace one specific page, leaving all the others untouched. So all but one pages in the resulting file will be the same as the original, using the same fonts or other resources just as before.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. This depends entirely on the tools you use. If they do not support resource merging there is nothing you can do. Probably you have to investigate other tools and see if they behave differently.

Comment: I've tried this sort of round-trip with poppler (pdfseparate + pdfunite). Interestingly, if I keep repeating this process, the (united) file size grows exponentially, but the (separated) files stay the same size.